# WPF pass DataGrid selected row as command parameter

Tags: wpf, binding

1. **MainWindowViewModel** has a **ViewCustomerCommand(string id)** command that shows a customer by id
2. **MainWindow.xaml** containing TabControl
3. TabControl has a UserControl that contains DataGrid that is bind to Customers collection
   | id | customer |

How do I pass "id" column in DataGrid selected row as a command parameter in **MainWindow.xaml**

```
MainWindow.xaml
    <Button Command="{Binding ViewCustomerCommand}" CommandParameter="??? how to pass id of selected customer ???" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you really need to expose the `SelectedItem` from within a `UserControl` why don't you extend it with such a property?

E.g.

```cs
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    private static readonly SomeType SelectedItemProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(SomeType), typeof(MyUserControl));

    public SomeType SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (SomeType)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

So now you can bind the `SelectedItem` of the `DataGrid` in the `UserControl` to its `SelectedItem` property.

```xml
<MyUserControl>
    <DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
              AncestorType={x:Type MyUserControl}}" />
</MyUserControl>
```

Now you only have to find a way to access the `SelectedItem` property in the `TabItem`. But I'm leaving that part to you.

Please note, that this is only an illustration of my idea and it may contain some small errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @DHN.
Your answer helped so much with a solution
I did as you told and created a SelectedCustomer property and bind it to DataGrid
`<UserControl>
    <DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer}" />
 </UserControl>`


And command parameter passed like following

**MainWindow.xaml**

    `<Button Command="{Binding ViewCustomerCommand}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Tabs[0].SelectedCustomer.Id}" />`